# How to return instance of concrete class from method with generic return type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method which is being called from my application. Method is implemented from `Google.Apis.Util.Store.IDataStore`. I would like to return token from that method, but I don't know how. Token is class type TokenResponse. How to return class TokenResponse from method like this?

```
public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{
  //TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse();
  //token.RefreshToken = @"rere545454545";
  //return token; -- I would like to return this, but it throws error
  return Task.FromResult<T>(default); //that works, but not much help out of it
}
```

**Update**

Basically I would like to return my own token, which I already have in database. But trying to make a new instance like:

```
TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse()
```

throws and error

> cannot create an instance of the variable type TokenResponse because
>   it does not have the new() constraint

Comment: Drop the generic arg from your method. You want to return a `Task<TokenResponse>`

Comment: This error is thrown if I change method's signature like Task<TokenResponse> GetAsync<TokenResponse>(string key)

Comment: change this `Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)` to this `Task<TokenResponse> GetAsync(string key)`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRandall this works. But the problem is, that IDataStore should implement this method. I have an error if I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to fix your problem is to use the next approach:

```
  public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
  {
     TokenResponse t = new TokenResponse();
     // ...
     return Task.FromResult((T) ((object) t));
  }
```

You should guarantee that the method `GetAsync<T>` will always be called with type parameter `T = TokenResponse`. Otherwise, this code will throw `InvalidCastException`.